# Bidirectional Layer in Keras: Unsupported Operand Type

Tags: keras

I’m getting an error for a bidirectional network along the lines of

```
model = Sequential()
model.add( Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True),
                         input_shape = input_shape[1:]) )
#model.add( Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True) ))
model.add( TimeDistributed(Dense(units = language_vocab_size, 
                 activation = 'softmax')) )
learning_rate = 0.01
model.compile(loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

The returned error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

What exactly causes this error?

Comment: You should post the entire stack trace. Or at least identify in which line the error is raised. This doesn't seem to be coming from this code.

Comment: Unless your input shape contains hidden "None"s where it's not supposed to.

Comment: Or "language_vocab_size".

Comment: I agree with @DanielMöller. The error can't be identified here. You should provide both the stack trace and `input_shape` and `language_vocab_size`